# How to solve the differential equation $xx'' = (x')^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is an differential given:
$$xx'' = (x')^2,$$
where $x' \neq 0.$
I tried to solve this problem but I cannot see the proper substitution.

Comment: $(x/x')'=((x')^2-xx'')/(x')^2$ may help.

Comment: Worth noting the next time you see a problem like this is that the closed-form solutions to second-degree differential equations of one variable often involve $c_1 \sin k_1 x + c_2 \cos k_2 x$, as the first and second derivatives have the same form. The $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ functions also often appear, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think that

$$
\frac{\ddot x}{\dot x} = \frac{\dot x}{x}\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\ln(\dot x) = \frac{d}{dt}\ln (x)
$$

so

$$
\ln(\dot x) = \ln(x) + C \Rightarrow \dot x = C_1 x\Rightarrow x = C_2e^{C_1 t}
$$

Comment: Thanks LutzL for the hint.

Answer (score 9):

The comment seen here uses a "trick". Here is a more standard solution.

The independent variable is not rendered explicitly so you have an **autonomous equation**.  Given this, put in $u=x'$.  Then

$$x''=\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t))=\frac{du}{dx}\, x'=u\,\frac{du}{dx}$$

using the Chain Rule.  So

$$x\cdot u\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=u^2$$

Divide by $u$ and solve the separable equation that results, then substitute $x'$ for $u$ into that first integration to get another first order equation that is easily solved.

Comment: Which works in this case because $u = x' \neq 0$.

Comment: Agreed.  Ironically, the solution gotten by assuming $u\ne 0$ also covers $u=0$ given the proper value of one integration constant.  Dumb luck strikes again!

Answer (score 5):

With the substitution $$v(x)=\frac{dx}{dt},$$ we get
$$x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}v(x)=(v(x))^2.$$
This can be written as
$$-v(x)\left(-x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+v(x)\right)=0,$$
so either $v(x)=0$ or
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{v(x)}{x}$$ and this is
$$\int\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{v(x)}dx=\int\frac{1}{x}dx.$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 5):

$$xx'' = (x')^2,$$
Divide by $x^2 \,\, x\neq 0)$
$$\frac {x''}x = \frac {(x')^2}{x^2}$$

Note that 
$$(\frac {x'}x)'= \frac {x''}x-\frac {x'^2}{x^2}$$
Therefore
$$\frac {x''}x = \frac {(x')^2}{x^2} \implies (\frac {x'}x)' =0$$
$$\frac {x'}x =K_1 \implies \ln|x|=K_1t+K_2 \implies x=K_2e^{K_1t} $$